# Unable to run shell script during jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job that should execute a script.

The commands of the build step are:

```
sh 'chmod +x ./load/bin/1.1.1_quality_results'
sh './load/bin/1.1.1_quality_results'
```

However I get the following error:

> sh: chmod +x ./load/bin/1.1.1_quality_results: No such file or
>   directory

but if I check the file structure, it does exist:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: maybe you're in the wrong folder. Try to add a `sh 'pwd'` or a `sh 'find . -name 1.1.1_quality_results'` to figure out the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason I do not know, the following does not work:

```
sh 'pwd'
sh 'commandsomthing'
```

but this works:

```
pwd
commandsomthing
```

So I had to remove the `sh ''` part:

```
chmod +x ./load/bin/1.1.1_quality_results
./load/bin/1.1.1_quality_results
```

Found by trying sh 'pwd' as said in the comments by Stefano